# Geometric picture of forces produced by anisotropic pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Consider a fluid which has two different pressures at each point. We can model that by choosing a unit vector field $\mathbf{n}$ and writing the 3D stress-energy tensor as

$$T_{ij} = (p_1 - p_2) n_i n_j + p_2 \delta_{ij},$$

so that in the direction of $\mathbf{n}$ the pressure is $p_1$ and in the two others it's $p_2$.

Now let's also add spherical symmetry, so that $p_1 = p_1(r)$ and $p_2 = p_2(r)$, and $\mathbf{n}$ is in the radial direction. The internal forces per unit volume on a piece of fluid are given by the divergence of the stress-energy tensor, which after some algebra turns out to be

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{T} = \left(\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial r} + \frac{2 p_1}{r} - \frac{2 p_2}{r}\right) \mathbf{n}.$$

If we take the special case of isotropic pressure, this is intuitive: the force is just the gradient of the pressure. One can see this by taking a small piece of fluid and adding the forces acting on its sides. Is it possible to arrive at the anisotropic result via a similar physical argument?